# Calculating the area of the set $B = \{ (x,y,z) \in R^3 | 4x^2+ y^2 - 1 \le z , 0 \le z \le 2y + 2 \}$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I want to calculate the area of the following set
$$B = \{ (x,y,z) \in R^3 | 4x^2+ y^2 - 1 \le z , 0 \le z \le 2y + 2 \}$$

This is part of an elliptic paraboloid (two planes cut it).

I thought that a correct integral to evaluate the area was

$$\int_C \int_0^{2y + 2} dz dxdy$$

Where $C$ is the set of all $y$, $x \in B$, so they must satisfy $4 x^2 + y^2 - 1 \le 2y + 2$. This means $$C =  \{ (x,y) \in R^2 | 4x^2 +(y-1)^2 \le 4 \}$$

In this way I could pass to modified cylindrical coordinates and get a fairly quick solution. But I made a mistake with the limits of integration or the set $C$, where is the mistake in my reasoning?

Comment: your limits are not taking into consideration how the plane z=0 intersects the paraboloid.  There is an inner radius to calculate.